# Updating state inside useCallback - React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I restructure this code to allow a state update inside the `useCallback` function?

Here's what is executed first:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, [getData]); // errors if getData is left (missing dependency error)
```

In the `getData` function, I pass a state variable (`lastDoc`) to `getSomething()` as a parameter. It stores the last document/database row for pagination.

```
const [lastDoc, setLastDoc] = useState(null);

const getData = useCallback(async() => {
    const data = await getSomething(lastDoc);
    setLastDoc(data.lastDoc); // useSate function
}, [getSomething, lastDoc]);
```

This, at the moment, just causes an infinite loop where the `getData` function is re-rendered once `setLastDoc` updates the `lastDoc` variable, as `getData` has `lastDoc` as a dependency. If I remove the `lastDoc` dependency, I get the missing dependency error, which I understand to be an important error to listen to.

Answer (score -2):

I think a null-check might be sufficient.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(lastDoc === null){
        getData();
    }
}, [getData, lastDoc]);
```